# Android Map Performance poor because of many Overlays?

Tags: android, performance, dictionary, overlay

I have a map in my android application that shows many markers (~20-50). But the app performs very poor when i try to scroll/zoom (in Google Android Maps i did a sample search for pizza and there were also some 20-50 results found and i didn't notice any particular performance problems when zooming/scrolling through the map).

Here is my (pseudo)code:

```
onCreate() {
    ....
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker1);
    itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,mapView);
    ...
    callWebServiceToRetrieveData();

    createMarkers();
}

createMarkers(){
    for(elem:bigList){
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(elem.getLat()*1000000), (int) (elem.getLon()*1000000));
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, elem.getName(), elem.getData());
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

        mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
}
mapView.invalidate();
```

}

the MyItemizedOverlay.addOverlay looks like this:

```
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    m_overlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If I understand how this works correctly, you should not be calling populate after every add an overlay.  You should do it once you've added them all.  I think what's happening is that you add the first `OverlayItem` and call `populate()` so it adds that to the `ItemizedOverlay.`  Then you add a second `OverlayItem` to the list and call `populate()` and it adds those *two* overlays to the `ItemizedOverlay` resulting in *three* items in the overlay.  So I think you're getting way more than the 20-50 that you think.

Comment: Not only that, but you can have more than one marker in an overlay. The way your pseudocode is written, you are adding the *same overlay* once per marker -- `mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);` -- which is not exactly going to help you.

Comment: Would be interesting to me, too.

Answer (score 6):

I've done the following now and it works fast(er):

```
createMarkers(){
    for(elem:bigList){
        GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(elem.getLat()*1000000), (int) (elem.getLon()*1000000));
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(geoPoint, elem.getName(), elem.getData());
        itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);

   }
   itemizedOverlay.populateNow();
   mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay); //outside of for loop
```

}

and in MyOverlay:

```
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    m_overlays.add(overlay);
}

public void populateNow(){
    populate();
}
```

is this better/correct now ? or any other improvements possible?

Comment: Much, much better this way. Thank you soo much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem last night, and my solution was the same as yours.  I felt weird about how I called the populate method.

I had the same code as you but I called

```
speedyPopulate() { 
  populate(); 
}
```

in the MyOverlay class